# getting address from location by geocoder not working in some devices

Tags: android, google-maps, google-geocoder

I'm trying to get address from location by geocoder and it working, but some time in some devices not working

## when clicking on marker get location from map and passing to this method but sometimes not working and my textview set text waiting for getting address

```
  private void getAddressFromLocation(final LatLng latlng, final TextView et) {
    et.setText(R.string.text_waiting_for_get_address);
    et.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Geocoder gCoder = new Geocoder(getActivity());
            try {
                final List<Address> list = gCoder.getFromLocation(
                        latlng.latitude, latlng.longitude, 1);
                if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
                    address = list.get(0);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    if (address.getAddressLine(0) != null) {
                        if (address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) { 
                              sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("-");
                            }
                            sb.append(address.getCountryName());
                        } else {
                            sb.append(address.getAddressLine(0));
                        }
                    }
                    strAddress = sb.toString();
                    strAddress = strAddress.replace("-null", "");
                    strAddress = strAddress.replace("-ایران", "");
                    strAddress = strAddress.replace("null", "");
                    strAddress = strAddress.replace("Unnamed", "");
                }
                if (getActivity() != null) {
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(strAddress)) {
                                et.setFocusable(false);
                                et.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
                                if (et.getTag().toString().equals("origin")) {
                                    et.setText("Origin : " + strAddress + "");
                                } else {
                                    et.setText("Destination : " + strAddress + "");
                                }
                                et.setFocusable(true);
                                et.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                            } else {
                                et.setText("");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            } catch (Exception exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the following issue from the Google issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35828055

Feel free to star it and add your comments. As a workaround, try to use [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding) web service.